# C# ODBC SELECT query with mm.dd.yyyy format date

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, odbc, date-format

I am using `c# ODBC query` on CSV data, which contains date with different format.
Like some column has `MM.DD.YYYY` format, while few has `MM-DD-YYYY` format.

How can I write `SELECT statement` to query on those column?

I tried `SELECT * FROM data.csv WHERE date1 <> #02-02-2018#`
Which has data stored like `02.02.2018`.

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM data.csv WHERE date1 <> #02-02-2018#";
OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(query, conn);
da.Fill(dataSet, table.Name);
```

What I expect is irrespective of CSV date format, it will execute `where` with given value.

|date1     |

|----------|

|02.02.2018|

|02/02/2018|

|02-02-2018|

Here above sample data which has different format on `date1` column.

Comment: You tried and what happened?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya It just either throws exception or not match condition.

Comment: None of these are actually `DATE`s. They're all some form of string (`CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, etc.). You need to use a more powerful ODBC driver for CSV data — i.e., one that can `CONVERT` from `STRING` to `DATE` — or bring that CSV into a real DBMS (and use an ODBC driver for that DBMS).

Answer (score 0):

Check this out http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '02-02-2018')
SELECT convert(datetime, '02/02/2018')
SELECT convert(datetime, '02.02.2018')
```

[image]

Comment: It throws exception, I don't think `CONVERT` will work here

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am using `ODBC SELECT query` on `CSV data`. Not on `SQL SERVER`

Answer (score 0):

As your date "field" isn't a date but a string, compare with text:

```
string query = @"SELECT * FROM data.csv WHERE date1 NOT IN ('02-02-2018','02.02.2018','02/02/2018')";
```

Comment: I've set that field as `Date` from ODBC connection. Still it requires to check as `string`?

Comment: But a field of data type Date doesn't carry a format, it's a value only. Even if casted to text, it couldn't be using three different formats - it would be with one format only.

Comment: If it contains only One format for one Column and another format for another column, But I don't know which column has which format. Then how can I use query against them?

Comment: Can't see that from here ... but did you check my query? As to your reported sample data, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ODBC can handle multiple datetime formats. To overcome this situation you must tell the `date1` column as text column in schema.ini (refer MSDN). Then you make the query to include all possible date format values as text values

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM data.csv WHERE date1 <> '02.02.2018' OR date1 <> '02-02-2018' OR date1 <> '02/02/2018'";
```

This is not elegant way to solve this issue. But it works.

On the second thought, if you don't want to compromise `date1` column datatype other than date type, you should sanitize your CSV file converting all `date1` values to one single date format, then use the converted file in ODBC to load them.

Hope you get the idea.